# how to use Bootbox with my jQuery Validation

Tags: jquery, validation, bootbox

I am trying to get the jQuery validation plugin to work with bootbox.js.

I would like just to show a message with bootbox instead an error label.
Here is my code

```js
   $().ready(function() {
 // validate the comment form when it is submitted
 $("#mainform").validate({
  debug: true ,
  rules: {  
      idmail: {
   required: true,
   minlength: 7,
   email: true
      } ,
      idnome: {
   required: true,
   minlength: 2
      } 
          },
   messages: {
   idmail: "please insert a valid mail",
   idnome: "please insert a name"
   }
 }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sets up validation for a form, then checks if the form is valid when clicking a button.</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/site-demos.css">
</head>
<form id="mainform">
      Email : <input type="text"  name="idmail" > <p>

     Name : <input type="text"  name="idnome" id="idnome">  

            <input type="submit" value ="Invia">
</form>
```